# can The death aura be used by minions?

Tags: path-of-exile

If I use a minion gem in death's oath my minion can have the same aura?

If not, Is there another way to do this?

Comment: I think it could work with animate guardian. Did anyone try that?

Comment: @Phil123 i checked about this and before the version 3 was possible to do because death aura was not a skill

Answer (score 1):

The "Grants Level 20 Death Aura Skill" behaves as a skill gem the same way a typical gem like Cyclone or Fireball does. You cannot "give" a minion skill gems by linking them together but it means you can support Death Aura with support gems [as seen under mechanics on its wiki page](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Death%27s_Oath#Mechanics).